# WCF or Service Bus Sessions for Request-Response

Tags: wcf, servicebus, azureservicebus

I am using On-Premise Service Bus 1.1 for communication between processes.

I need to perform request-response methods between end points and need to decide if I will use WCF or the bus (Service Bus Relay for WCF is not currently available for on premise).

- WCF would be easiest to talk to via a generated client proxy, potential complexity with IIS host (or self host) and versioning of clients calling the service.
- For Service Bus create two queues per remote service (i.e.
  userService, userServiceResponse) and then use sessions. Flexible versioning with different commands. Management of these queues could become complex.
- For my project everything is within the same subnet and if required WCF endpoints could talk directly to one another

To help me decide which technology to use, my questions are:

1. Where would WCF be used over request-response service bus?
2. Are there any libraries for Service Bus queues to implement
   request-response messaging (or any robust code examples)?
3. If we have multiple publishers on a queue, how would we return a reply to a specific sender? Would we have multiple serviceReponse queues, or can a single return queue be used?

Comment: research "scatter gather" pattern...and add "service bus" to the search string.  RabbitMQ has a good scatter/gather setup, not sure about Service Bus, but I would think they would be similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service Bus messages can have a `SessionID` unique for that request where the service will receive the message, do something with it and reply with a message that has the same ID in the `ReplyToSessionID`. This allows the requesting party to receive based on the Session ID like this

```
MessageSession sessionReceiver = _queueClient.AcceptMessageSession(_mySessionID,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
sessionReceiver.Peek();
```

I think the big question here is Sync vs Async whether you want the requesting party to sit back and wait for a response (WCF) or back later and check if the response is ready yet Service Bus but that is a business decision.

This [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-Request-2b4ff5d8) or this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863132.aspx) might help you get started with Req/Rep for SB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that deciding which technology should be used is a business decision. At first, it's a technical one.
I would not go with a product which is very operating system dependent, and worst, it's so premature. We *can* be creating coupling (OS x Bus) and  stepping over a mined field. 
But, this is only a personal opinion and might be biased as I'm not a Azure SB specialist.

I agree with @Tom, your decision is more related to sync/async model.

Some questions I usually answer before deciding on this subject:

1. Can we preview the rate of requests/minute and the amount of clients?
2. What is the nature of the service? Heavy processing logic or simple queries against a database?

I can list some others if you wish, but those two can easily help on the decision, forcing you to think broadly.